# Smart pointers with functions returning a pointer in an argument

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, std, standard-library

This question was discussed a few times but all those discussions almost a decade old and there was no good solution. The question is the same.

We have smart pointers, like `unique_ptr`, that is great. We have tons of C functions returning a pointer to an object as an argument which later needs to be released.

Let's say this is the function:

```
int CreateSomething(OBJECT_TYPE** pObject);
```

So, what would we normally do without smart pointers? Apparently something like that:

```
OBJECT_TYPE* pObject;
if(CreateSomething(&pObject) == 0) {
    // Use the pObject pointer
    delete pObject;
}
```

Now, I would like to rewrite it using smart pointers, and I would like it to be as simple as this:

```
unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE> pObject;
if(CreateSomething(&pObject) == 0) {
    // Use the pObject pointer
}
```

Technically, that would be quite possible if `unique_ptr` would have `T** operator&`, and if it would count on this kind of workflow, but it doesn't.

In the case when we want to use a smart pointer here, we have to declare a regular pointer, use it in that function, and then reassign it to the smart pointer. But those extra steps can and should be eliminated, and I hope that maybe there is already an implementation which would allow me to do what I need in that simple manner as I showed.

Yes, I can write my own smart pointer or mediator, which would simplify the usage of `unique_ptr`, but first I'd like to ask if maybe there is already something implemented in the depth of standard libraries for this and I simply overlooked it?

Comment: Wouldn't `pObject.get()` do what you need? In this case it would return `OBJECT_TYPE**`, since `T = OBJECT_TYPE*`

Comment: @Lala5th no, `get()` will not work in this case. The example is wrong, it should be using `unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE>` instead of `unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE*>`

Answer (score 3):

C++23 has very recently added [`std::out_ptr`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p1132r8.html) for exactly this use case.

Answer (score 2):

write a wrapper: (uncompiled code)

```
namespace smart_ptrs {
std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE> CreateSomething() {
    OBJECT_TYPE *p = nullptr;
    if (::CreateSomething(&p))
      return std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE>(p);
    return std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE>();
}
```

Then you can write:

```
std::unique_ptr<OBJECT_TYPE> ptr = smart_ptrs::CreateSomething();
if (ptr) {
   // Use the pObject pointer
   }
```

Comment: The OP did say: "*Yes, I can write my own smart pointer **or mediator**, which would simplify the usage of `unique_ptr`, but first I'd like to ask if ...*" so you are not actually answering the question that was really asked.

Answer (score 1):

> In the case when we want to use a smart pointer here, we have to declare a regular pointer, use it in that function, and then reassign it to the smart pointer.

Basically, yes.  That is exactly what you must do (for now anyway, until [`std::out_ptr` is added in C++23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716013/65863)).

C++ smart pointers simply do not expose access to their held pointer, thus no way for you to obtain its address to pass to the C function.  So, you have to use the smart pointer's constructor or assignment operator instead, which requires the object pointer to already be initialized first.

> I'd like to ask if maybe there is already something implemented in the depth of standard libraries for this and I simply overlooked it?

You have not overlooked anything.